# GWT Modules and Web Pages

Tags: gwt, module

I am new to GWT and am going through the docs, examples, demos etc.

All the examples seem to have just one module which is loaded by a single html page contained in the sample.

What if the web app has multiple web pages/features. Can multiple web pages providing different functionality utilize the same gwt module by building the UI differently based on request params?

Or is it normal to create one module per html page (feature) in the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at these two questions:

- [Multiple pages tutorial in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-gwt)
- [GWT with multiple host pages in a legacy application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363136/gwt-with-multiple-host-pages-in-a-legacy-application)

...or at [this site](http://examples.roughian.com/) which guides you through the process, if you are new I strongly suggest to subscribe to the 5 days email course.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a GWT module contains multiple 'screens', or 'views'.

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes you can have multiple different pages in a GWT app.

Full: You can do his in several ways, the easiest is to use the XML file where you can list the various URL points (the same you use to specify the RPC call back URL) to list multiple URL's and the corresponding classes (each class will need to inherit the correct classes to ensure it is a front end)

You can also simply generate different screens based on different variables in the same class, however this will complicate the code and lead to messy designs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using less number of the pages that needs full page reload to interact is better in GWT.
In generally, you can to divide logic to many tabs, screens, windows and other layouts, that can interact without page reloading.
See on the google mail )